# Login page shows inside UpdateTargetId when ajax action is [Authorize]

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a AJAX form & a action method corresponding to that Form. I want this form keep  [Authorize].

AJAX Form:

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Vote", "Rate", null ,
                       new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                               OnFailure = "searchFailed",
                               LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
                               UpdateTargetId = "searchresults",
                           },new { id = "voteForm" }))
                {
                <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="1">
                <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="2">
                <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="3">
                <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
                }
```

And Authorized Action

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Vote(Rate rate)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Rates.Add(rate);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

    return PartialView("_Vote");

       }
```

When I Click on Submit Button the login Page shows inside the  UpdateTargetId(searchresults), But it need to show it in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing an Ajax action and all results will be reflected inside the `UpdateTargetId`.

So you should check for this particular case where user is un-authorized in the `OnFailure` or `OnSuccess` methods using the responseText from server and redirect the user to login page using javascript i.e

```
location.href = '/login';
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. It fires success method. But I couldn't identify the it is authenticated or not.